# What is a reasonable number of threads for a Java program?

Tags: java, architecture, multithreading

In Java (or probably most other languages targeting the JVM) what is a reasonable number of threads to use? Presumably, this will be expressed as a ratio to the number of cores/processors available, is that correct?

At least initially, it seems like twice as many threads as cores might make sense, but 20+ times as many seems unreasonable. Is the ratio likely to be affected by the type and/or architecture of the software? Are there types of software and/or situations in which a much larger number of threads really makes sense?

[And yes, I know that's phrased as a number of separate questions, but I think they're closely enough related for a single answer to cover all of them, since they're all really about how many threads make sense under what circumstances.]

Comment: I bet you won't like Erlang.

Comment: It depends on where you are bound. More threads than cores is not really all that bad.

Comment: @Rig I can see that with, say, ~8 threads on quad-core machine, but with 20 or a 100, task switching overhead becomes significant.

Comment: Hi David, all questions here are expected to be asked in a fair and impartial tone: ranting is not what we do here. If you can rephrase your question to something that's specifically answerable that doesn't doesn't contain a rant, feel free to do so and flag your question for moderator review.

Comment: So you are saying most of the complex software we use is wrong? Looking at Firefox on my mac with 2 tabs open I see it is running 26 threads...42 if you include the flash plugin. Chrome 33. Even my terminal is running 5...

Comment: I've tried to turn this into a question that's at least reasonably closely related to the original, while still having at least some chance of being open to constructive answers (though I haven't looked carefully -- I may have turned it into a duplicate of an existing question).

Comment: Use as many threads as you need, and no more.

Comment: @MarkTrapp I didn't mean this to come across as the rant; I think the edits took care of that. My frustration was about the lack of relation of architecture as it's been presented to me to awareness of implementation details, not about the language.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks for the edits; it's a lot closer to what I meant to ask now. :)

Comment: @Rig Given that Firefox consumes around 1GB of RAM with 3 tabs open on my machine at the moment, I'd hardly hold it up as an example of good design. If there's a good reason to do it that way, I'd love to hear it, but in my experience there's rarely a reason to spawn dozens of threads without supporting hardware. If most of them are idle most of the time, then why bother with threads at all?

Comment: @DavidLively You must be suffering some other issue then. I have it open with several plugins and tabs and am at <150MB

Comment: What do your performance tests say?  For the kind of work that I do (processing and analysis of large data files), one thread per processor core is ideal.

Answer (score 5):

Lots of comments, but no answer, yet. Here's a quick stab...

I would say that it depends on what your threads are doing. You can have hundreds of threads, but if the vast majority of them are just waiting, they won't incur much overhead. On the other hand, if you are doing computation, I would limit the number of threads to the number of cores. You won't get any extra pure computation speed from scheduling more. In addition, in these cases, you may want to look into task parallelism as an alternative.

If your code is a mix of waiting and processing, the answer is less clear. Aside from various strategies you can take to speed things up, your best bet in this case is to do profiling to find an optimal number.

Comment: Actually I would want about a 2:1 ratio or even 3:1 between threads and cores, so that when something blocks something else can be swapped in. In Erlang generally you would want something like a 100:1 or more, but Erlang uses a much lighter weight process model